# Django: Testing LoginView throwing AssertionError

Tags: django, django-testing

**Quesiton**
I'm building a testing suite for my login process and immediately ran into a hiccup. I believe the issue is that LoginView is a 'class' while the code is testing it as a function. What is the proper way to assert that the URL resolved to the LoginView?

**urls.py**

```
from . import views
from users.views import *

from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView
from users.forms import LoginForm


urlpatterns = [
     path('', views.user_home_view, name='user_home'),
     path('sign_up', views.SignUpView.as_view()),
     path('login', LoginView.as_view(authentication_form=LoginForm), name='login'),
     path('logout', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout')
]
```

**tests.py**

```
from django.test import SimpleTestCase
from django.urls import reverse, resolve
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView
from users.forms import LoginForm
from users.views import *

# Create your tests here.

class UrlTestCase(SimpleTestCase):

    def test_login_url_resolved(self):
        url = reverse('login')
        self.assertEquals(resolve(url).func, LoginView)
```

**Testing Results (./manage.py test**)

*AssertionError: <function LoginView at 0x7f970ca05320> != <class 'django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView'>*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are not getting back instance of `LoginView` class but appropriate method through `as_view()` entry point method

You can access class through attribute `view_class` which is set in `as_view()`  method as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view)

> The returned view has view_class and view_initkwargs attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Solution

```
self.assertEquals(resolve(url).func.view_class, LoginView)
```

See this: [django how to assert url pattern resolves to correct class based view function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27320821/django-how-to-assert-url-pattern-resolves-to-correct-class-based-view-function)